# AngularJS ng-repeat and select control updating all instances

Tags: angularjs

I have this bit of HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name / Number</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="player in item.players">
                <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="player.gender" ng-options="gender.id as gender.title for gender in item.garment.modifiers[0].variants" ng-change="controller.updateCart(item)">
                        <option value="">Please select</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="player.qty" ng-change="controller.updateCart(item)">
                        <option ng-repeat="qty in garmentController.quantities">{{ qty }}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-icon-only btn-icon-only" type="button" ng-click="garmentController.remove(item, player)"><span class="fa fa-close"></span></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This table is in another ng-repeater which looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-order" id="{{ item.garment.slug }}" ng-repeat="item in garmentController.order.items">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <label class="control-label">{{ item.garment.title }}</label>

            <div class="kit-template" garment="item.garment" colours="controller.kit.data.colours" on-complete="garmentController.onLoad(item.garment.slug)" kd-kit-designer></div>

            <p class="lead">{{ item.garment.price.price }}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div kd-garment-current-configuration="{{ item.garment.slug }}" ng-if="garmentController.hasLoaded(item.garment.slug)">
                hello
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div alert type="info" ng-if="!garmentController.fulfilledQuantities(item)">
                Please be aware that we can not accept order quantities less than 10 per item. Adjust your quanities below to fix this issue.
            </div>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name / Number</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="player in item.players">
                            <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="player.gender" ng-options="gender.id as gender.title for gender in item.garment.modifiers[0].variants" ng-change="controller.updateCart(item)">
                                    <option value="">Please select</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="player.qty" ng-change="controller.updateCart(item)">
                                    <option ng-repeat="qty in garmentController.quantities">{{ qty }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-icon-only btn-icon-only" type="button" ng-click="garmentController.remove(item, player)"><span class="fa fa-close"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Say I have 3 items but only 1 player for each item, when I change the quantity dropdown, all the items dropdowns change to that value and I am not sure why.
Can someone help me stop it doing that?

I created a codepen to highlight the issue, but the codepen actually does what I want.

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/vOMeZW?editors=101

I have no idea why that one is working, because the order that I have statically declared is an exact copy of my test output on my dev machine.

### A bit more information

Just to make it easier to guess what might be happening, here are my resolves that are making up the order:

```
// Get the kit we are ordering
kit: ['$stateParams', 'KitService', function ($stateParams, service) {

    // Return our kit
    return service.get($stateParams.kitId);
}],

// Get he team that the kit belongs to
team: ['kit', function (kit) {

    // Return our team
    return kit.data.team;
}],            

// Get the garments assigned to the kit
garments: ['$q', 'Moltin', 'kit', function ($q, moltin, kit) {

    // Get the garments
    var garments = kit.data.garments;

    // Create our deferred promise
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // Create our array of promises
    var promises = [];

    // Create our array of results
    var results = [];

    // Loop through our garments
    for (var i = 0; i < garments.length; i++) {

        // Get our garment
        var garment = garments[i];

        // Push our promise to our promises array
        promises.push(moltin.products.get(garment.slug).success(function (response) {

            // Combine both models
            var combined = angular.extend(response[0], garment);

            // Push our result into our results array
            results.push(combined);
        }));
    }

    // Resolve all our promises
    $q.all(promises).then(function () {

        // Resolve our results
        deferred.resolve(results);
    });

    // Return our promise
    return deferred.promise;
}],

// Get the players already added to the team
players: ['team', function (team) {

    // Return our players
    return team.players;
}],

// Gets the customer if they have placed an order before, if not it will return the new customer to be created
customer: ['$rootScope', 'Moltin', function ($rootScope, moltin) {

    // Get our user
    var user = $rootScope.user;

    // If we have a customer id
    if (user.customerId) {

        // Get our customer
        return moltin.custsomers.get(user.customerId);
    }

    // If we don't have a customer id return the new customer object
    return {
        first_name: user.firstName,
        last_name: user.lastName,
        email: user.email
    };
}],

// Gets the stored addresses if we have a customer
addresses: ['customer', 'Moltin', function (customer, moltin) {

    // If we have a customer id
    if (customer.id) {

        // Get our addresses
        return moltin.customers.addresses(customer.id);
    }

    // Return nothing fallback
    return null;
}],

// Create our order
order: ['garments', 'players', function (garments, players) {

    // Create our order
    var order = {
        items: []
    };

    // Loop through our garments
    for (var i = 0; i < garments.length; i++) {

        // Get our current garment
        var garment = garments[i];

        // Create our item
        var item = {
            garmentId: garment.id,
            garment: garment,
            players: players
        };

        // Push our items to our array
        order.items.push(item);
    }

    // Return our order
    return order;
}],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected this was due to how I was assigning my players to each order item. I was actually assigning the reference to the players array, so when a player was being change the 2 way binding took effect and changed all other references to players.
The way I solved this was by changing the order resolve to do this:

```
// Create our order
order: ['garments', 'players', function (garments, players) {

    // Create our order
    var order = {
        items: []
    };

    // Loop through our garments
    for (var i = 0; i < garments.length; i++) {

        // Get our current garment
        var garment = garments[i];

        var t = [];

        for (var n = 0; n < players.length; n++) {

            var player = players[n];

            t.push({ id: player.id, name: player.name, positionNumber: player.positionNumber, teamId: player.teamId });
        }

        // Create our item
        var item = {
            garmentId: garment.id,
            garment: garment,
            players: t
        };

        // Push our items to our array
        order.items.push(item);
    }

    // Return our order
    return order;
}],
```

As you can see, what I do is loop through the garments, then loop through the players. When looping through the players I push a new object (with the same properties as a player) to an array which I then assign to the item object.
This is pretty ugly, but it works.

If anyone has a more elegant solution please let me know.

### Turns out there is a better solution

Angular to the rescue, you can simple using **angular.copy()** to create a copy of the object / array like this:

```
// Create our order
order: ['garments', 'players', function (garments, players) {

    // Create our order
    var order = {
        items: []
    };

    // Loop through our garments
    for (var i = 0; i < garments.length; i++) {

        // Get our current garment
        var garment = garments[i];

        // Create our item
        var item = {
            garmentId: garment.id,
            garment: garment,
            players: angular.copy(players)
        };

        // Push our items to our array
        order.items.push(item);
    }

    // Return our order
    return order;
}],
```